# Oriented vs. Ordered Simplicial Homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

These are isomorphic homologies, and I found a sketch of a proof [here on p. 53.](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math205C-2011/morganalgtop.pdf)

The proof is mostly exercises, done in steps first for finite complexes, then for infinite ones, using the fact that homology commutes with direct limits. The only experience I have with theories of homology is that I am currently reading Rotman, and doing most of the exercises. When I read the statement and proof of the Acyclic Carrier theorem, it occurred to me that there might be a much easier proof of the aforementioned isomorphism-so my proof is probably wrong. But I would like feedback on my idea:

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex, whose vertices have been partially ordered in some way. Now, $C_n(K)$ and $C_n^{or}(K)$ are the free abelian groups of oriented and ordered, resp., $n$-simplices. Write the generators $[v_1,\cdots, v_n]$ and $<v_1,\cdots,v_n>,\ $ resp., and define

$f:C_n(K)\to C_n^{or}(K):[v_1,\cdots, v_n]\mapsto <v_1,\cdots,v_n>$ ; 
$g:C_n^{or}(K)\to C_n(K):<v_1,\cdots,v_p>\mapsto \begin{cases} 
       [v_1,\cdots, v_n]& v_i\neq v_j;\ 0\le i\neq j\le n \\
      0& \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$

Extend $f$ and $g$ by linearity. $f$ and $g$ are evidently augmentation-preserving chain maps. Furthermore,

$\tag 1 g\circ f=1_{C_n(K)}$

Now, define a function $E$ that maps the basis element  $\gamma= <v_1,\cdots,v_n>$ of $C_n^{or}(K)$ to $E(\gamma)$, the subcomplex consisting of $\gamma$ and its faces. Then $E$ is a carrier function for $f\circ g$ and $1_{C^{or}(K)}$ so the Acyclic Carrier theorem gives

$\tag2 f\circ g\sim 1_{C^{or}(K)}$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2),$ we conclude that $f$ and $g$ are chain homotopy inverses, so that $f_*$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: There are various variants of acyclic carrier theorems. Can you please give details what you want to use?

Comment: Munkres discusses this in his book Elements of Algebraic Topology, also using acyclic carriers. I don't think he does it separately for finite and arbitrary complexes, but I may not be remembering correctly.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: I will see if I can find Munkres book online. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulFrost: if $\phi$ is a chain map: $S_*\to T_*$ then $E$ is a carrier function for $\phi$ if $E$ assigns to each basis element $\gamma\in S_n$ a subcomplex $E(\gamma)$ of $T_*$ such that $E(\gamma)$  is acyclic; $\phi_n(\gamma)\in E_n(\gamma);$  and $\beta<\gamma\Rightarrow E(\beta)\subseteq E(\gamma)$ where $<$ means "is a face of."

Comment: Then everything is correct.